# Making head's or tails out of Window's Store Health reports

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

My app has some bugs that show up in the health report.  I was able to squash one, but there are a few others that I am having trouble interpreting.  Is there any way to send exception information to the Store's Health report, so that I can know what part of the code is crashing.  Have the health report, instead of gibberish like,,, STOWED_EXCEPTION_System.InvalidOperationException_80131509_EssentialVideoRecorder.dll!RHBinder__ShimExeMain   I can see a message that I created, so that I'll know what is doing what.  Thanks, John.  PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to send exception information to the Store's Health report, so that I can know what part of the code is crashing

The event is logged in OS when your app crashes and the device will send the event to the Windows Store central crash reporting system. But to minimize network and CPU impact, only core crash meta data (like OS, app version and function failed) will be sent. You could follow the steps below with Health report to debug your app:

•   Filter the page by Package Version (in the top of the page), to find the latest crashes

•   Filter the trend graph by OS version and market to narrow down issues

•   Review the breakout charts to determine if the issue corresponds to a particular OS version or device characteristics

•   Once you have narrowed the issue to a particular version of the app, OS or device, go to the Failure Log to view **stack traces** and diagnose the possible source of the issue

More info, please look into this [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/13/crash-analysis-in-the-unified-dev-center/#lCgiLkEYequxPvt5.97).

Alternatively, you can programmatically retrieve this data using the Windows Store analysis REST API. See [Get error reporting data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-error-reporting-data?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: That sounds not too far from what I've tried.  What I dreamt up today, but am not sure if it will work.  Trap all my errors, then depending on where the error was raise a particular error.  ie, if the error is the camera was removed while the program was running, I could raise an error like , Divide by 0.  Not that that has anything to do with what went wrong, but, if I look in the health report, and see it, I'll know where the error was.

Comment: My apologies. As it turns out the information provided in the reports is all we are able to provide currently.
You might refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2859130) which is a little old but still has some good tips

Comment: This just took a while to learn how to read.  I'm ok now.  Thought my usage report was in error, it turns out it was that I hadn't got handle on these bugs.  Now I have a clean health report, and usage is coming back nicely.  Many Thanks!  John.